# Laravel Array & JSON casting

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) to insert data in JSON format into table. What I would like to know is if it is possible to change one property of JSON object after it is inserted into table with more then one properties. For example:

```
Table:
+----+----------------------------------+
| id |               car                |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | {"brand": "audi", "model": "TT"} |
+----+----------------------------------+

$entity = Table::where('id', 1);
$entity->car['model'] = 'Aicon';
```

Code, similar to this, gives me an exception `'ErrorException' with message 'Indirect modification of overloaded property ... has no effect' in ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Such as in the Doc’s example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) you cannot, you have to take the JSON object (as an array), change it, and then put it back.

```
$entity = Table::where('id', 1);
$car = $entity->car;
$car['model'] = 'Aicon';
$entity->car = $car;
$entity->save();
```

Comment: You beat me to it, arg!

Comment: Wow, that's great! Thank you mate, this is just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly modify a child node of an attribute as it technically doesn't exist on the model. Scroll up just a few notches in the documentation link you shared and read up on [Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), alternatively just define the property properly.

If you don't want to automatically cast the JSON to array as @Thomas Edwards pointed out, you can define a mutator which essentially does the exact same thing, but you can modify as you wish:

```
public function getCarAttribute($value) 
{
   return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

Then append your new attributes to the mutated field:

```
$entity = Entity::find(1);

$car = $entity->car;
$car['model'] = 'Aicon';
$car['color'] = 'Blue';

$entity->car = $car;
$entity->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I'm gonna use @Thomas Edwards solution on this one.

Comment: He was first in the race in any event ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If the column is cast as a JSON column, then updating is very straightforward using an arrow accessor:

Cast:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'car' => 'json',
];
```

Updating:

```php
Table::find(1)->update(['car->model' => 'Aicon']);
```

More information on JSON columns in Laravel in a recent blog article I wrote: https://nullthoughts.com/development/2019/01/29/laravel-json-column-types/

**Edit:** If you are declaring the column as `$fillable`, I believe you'll have to add each property for mass-assignment using the arrow accessor:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'car->model',
];
```

Comment: Thank you @Makyen, I had quickly searched to see if this was even permitted while rushing to post my answer. As with anything, you learn more as you go, so I do appreciate the information early on. I've edited the post to reflect that the link is to my own blog.